# Run multiple storm topologies in local mode

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am having two separate topologies in my main() method. I am using 'for loop' to set its corresponding spout and bolts and submit that topology aswell. 
each topology is having separate set of spout and bolts with different logic in them.

Now I want to call different spouts and bolts dynamically. How can I do that ??

code in main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,Exception            
    {
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();



    try{
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/praveen /workspace/OfferEngine/OfferListJSON.json"));
        //ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
        String str="";
        String str1="";
        while((str1=in.readLine())!=null)
        {
            str = str + str1;
        }

         JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
         JsonObject o = (JsonObject)parser.parse(str);
         JsonObject o2 = (JsonObject)o.get("OfferData");

         ArrayList<String> ol = new ArrayList<String>();
         ol.add(o2.get("strOfferId").toString().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""));
         ol.add(o2.get("strOfferId1").toString().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""));

         TopologyBuilder bu = null;
         Config config = new Config();
         config.setDebug(false);

         for(String x : ol) {
                System.out.println(x); //prints element x
                String y="", z="";
                bu = new TopologyBuilder();         
                bu.setSpout(x, new Off1Spout(x).ks(), 2);
                y = x+"2";
                bu.setBolt(y, new main.java.bolts.Off1Bolt()).shuffleGrouping(x);
                z = x+"offerlimit";
                bu.setBolt(z, new OfferLimit()).shuffleGrouping(y);
cluster.submitTopology(x,config,bu.createTopology());
              }
    }

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any kind of suggestion is more helpfull... thanks regards

Comment: just a thought, what if by creating a factory for Spouts, which takes a String type and based on that returns required Spout .. it will be like a very simple factory. But then again if your condition increases you need to make changes in the simple factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try if() condition inside the for loop for different offers...See the below code for your reference

```
for(String x : ol) {
     System.out.println(x); 
//  Offer 1 related Topology
    if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("offer1")){                   
       String y="", z="";
       bu = new TopologyBuilder();          
       bu.setSpout();
       y = x+"start";
       cluster.submitTopology(x,config,bu.createTopology());
    }

//      Offer 2 related Topology

 if(x.equalsIgnoreCase("off2")){

       String y="", z="";
       bu = new TopologyBuilder();          
       bu.setSpout(x, new Off1Spout(x).ks(), 2);
       y = x+"start";
       bu.setBolt(y, new off2Bolt()).shuffleGrouping(x);
       cluster.submitTopology(x,config,bu.createTopology());
  }
}
```

How many Topologies are there create that many if condition..